# Factoring a quadratic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, factoring

On page 7 of “Elliptic Tales: curves, counting and number theory” the authors state that:

$(m^2+1)x^2+(2mb)x+(b^2-1)=0$

Has the factors:

$(m^2+1)(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=0$

Where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots.
Probably this is simple and I’m just rusty but I really don’t see where this comes from, could someone explain? The book states this as though it is a common feature of quadratics but if so it’s unfamiliar to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general property of quadratic functions and has nothing much to do with this particular quadratic. For any quadratic function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, if $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are its roots, then
$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c=a(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)$$
Similarly, if $P(x)$ is any polynomial of degree $d$ with leading coefficient $c$, it holds that
$$P(x)=c\prod_{k=1}^d (x-\alpha_i)$$
where $\alpha_i$ are the roots of $P(x)$.

See [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem).

Comment: I don’t for a second doubt you (though I’m amazed I wasn’t taught this or don’t recall it) but is there a source or reference I can look at to know more?

Comment: Ah you’ve added a link now

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$(m^2+1)x^2+(2mb)x+(b^2-1)= Ax^2 +Bx +C$$

Where $$A= (m^2+1)$$ and $$B= 2mb$$ and $$C= b^2-1$$

Every quadratic equation $$Ax^2 +Bx +C$$ factors as $$A(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$$ where $x_1$ and $x_2$ may be complex, but we can find them by the quadratic formula. $$x=\frac {-B\pm \sqrt {B^2-4AC}}{2A}$$